# Can a Mellin / Laplace Transform-like method be done with functions beside $x^{s-1}, e^{-st}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, laplace-transform, mellin-transform

Was wondering if using other kernel functions beside these would result in illucidating *other* types of formulas than what the above two well-known transform methods typically handle.

I don't necessarily need an in depth explanation if you've tried it before.  Just say "you'll run into trouble finding an inverse." etc.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many Laplace-transformable functions. They have to be of exponential order, or the transform integral doesn't converge. And yes, depending on the nature of the transformed functions, you might have to evaluate the complex line integral that defines the inverse LT.

Comment: @AdrianKeister you're saying there are more *Laplace* transformable funcitons, but I'm refering to a possible generalization of the Laplace transform.  Do you mean that as well ?

Comment: Yes, there are more Laplace-transformable functions than what you've listed. But there are also loads more transforms, including Fourier, Gelfand, and others. There are even concepts like the Inverse Scattering Transform method that takes this idea to a whole new level.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) is an (obviously incomplete) list of integral transforms.